# Como transformar resultado(linha) em colunas dinamicamente com o mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Em minha única turma tenho 2 alunos, 4 avaliações e 2 matérias.

Cada aluno faz 2 avaliações de cada matéria.

> Para ilustrar posso dizer que meus 2 alunos se chamam Carlos e Joana.
> Carlos e Joana fizeram a avaliação(1) da matéria Português e depois
> fizeram a avaliação(2) também de Português. Carlos e Joana fizeram a
> avaliação(3) da matéria Matemática e depois fizeram também a
> avaliação(4) de Matemática

Eu tenho 1 tabela [resultado] com os resultados dos alunos nas avaliações

| id | turma_id | avaliacao_id | usuario_id | nota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 10 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 8 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 9 |

E 1 outra tabela [avaliacao] com as informações sobre as avalições

| id | turma_id | materia_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |

Estou rodando a query:

```
SELECT 
resultado.usuario_id as alunoId, 
resultado.turma_id as turmaId, 
avaliacao.materia_id as materiaId,
avaliacao.id as avaliacaoId,
resultado.nota as resultadoNota
FROM resultado
LEFT JOIN avaliacao on avaliacao.id = resultado.avaliacao_id
WHERE resultado.turma_id = 1
```

e obtendo este resultado:

| alunoId | turmaId | materiaId | avaliacaoId | resultadoNota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 9 |

Mas eu gostaria de obter este resultado:

| alunoId | turmaId | materiaId | resultadoNota(1) | resultadoNota(2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 9 |

E caso houvesse mais avaliações da mesma matéria, deveria gerar algo parecido com isso:

| alunoId | turmaId | materiaId | resultadoNota(1) | resultadoNota(2) | ... resultadoNota(n) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Como obter esse resultado?

Estou usando 10.4.18-MariaDB

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT CASE IIF

Comment: Obrigado pelo norte! Mas to achando melhor arrumar o resultado via javascript mesmo...

Comment: Pivot dinâmico via SQL é sempre trabalhoso mesmo.